# Output arrays to files

Tags: powershell

I have some code that imports a file, groups the data by jobtitle, and then creates an array named for each job title.  Each array contains all of the employee IDs associated with that job title.  I need to output the employee IDs for each job title to a separate file named for the job title. So I need to export the array called Customer Service to a file named Customer Service.  The file needs to contain each of the employee IDs (the elements in the array).

I can export all employee IDs to a single file using:

```
Import-Csv $Results | Group-Object "jobtitle" | %{
    Set-Variable ($_.Name) ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID | Add-Content $outfile)
}
```

However, I need the employee IDs for each job title to be in a different file named after the job title.  So, I've tried `ForEach-Object`, `foreach` and the following, but can't get this right.

```
Import-Csv $Results | Group-Object "jobtitle" | %{
    Set-Variable ($_.Name) ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID |  Set-Content {"C:\Users\$env:username\Documents\Results\$_.Name $_.Group"})
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that weird `Set-Variable` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the output filename inside the loop and write the IDs to the file:

```
Import-Csv $Results | Group-Object "jobtitle" | ForEach-Object {
    $file = 'C:\some\folder\{0}.txt' -f $_.Name
    $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand ID | Set-Content $file
}
```

Comment: Ansgar,

Thanks so much for your help. I'm getting an error when I run the code using C:\users\admin\documents as the path:
Import-Csv $Results | Group-Object "jobtitle" | ForEach-Object {
    $file = 'C:\Users\admin\documents\{0}.txt' -f $_.Group
    $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand ID | set-content $file
    }

The error is:
set-content : An object at the specified path C:\Users\admin\documents\System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject].txt does not exist, or has 
been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Durr Sorry, my mistake. You need `$_.Name` for building the output file name, of course. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Things are great, and I can finish the script I've been working on.

Can't tell you how much I appreciate your time.

Comment: Yes, sir.  Done.